# BeautifulSoup RSS Feed extract a tab retruning "1"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using python3, BeautifulSoup, trying to get rss feed, in  `<description>` tag inside there is `<a>` and `<img>` tag.

I want to get only

1. `<a>` tag href
2. `<img>` tag src

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import CData

tp_api = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128936835.cms"
response = requests.get(tp_api)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'xml')
results = soup.find_all('item',)
records = []
for result in results:
    main = result.find('description').string
    images = main
    print(main)
```

Response we got

```
<a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/maharashtra-congress-demands-complete-loan-waiver-for-flood-hit-farmers/articleshow/70675961.cms"><img border="0" hspace="10" align="left" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/70675961.cms" /></a>The Congress on Wednesday sought a complete loan waiver for farmers affected by floods in Maharashtra and demanded that the state government provide them an assistance of Rs 60,000 per hectare of crop damage.
```

Comment: So, the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import CData

tp_api = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128936835.cms"
response = requests.get(tp_api)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('item',)
records = []
for result in results:
    main = BeautifulSoup(result.find('description').string, 'html.parser')
    a_tag = main.find('a')
    images = a_tag


print(a_tag)
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/delhi-hc-stays-jnu-inquiry-against-teachers-for-participating-in-protest/articleshow/70676842.cms"><img align="left" border="0" hspace="10" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/70676842.cms" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;"/></a>
```